# Object is String[] in c#

Tags: c#

How to check `object` is `String[]` .

For Example:

To check `object` is `enum`

```
  if (value.GetType().IsEnum)
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simple apply the [is operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) to check type.

> An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.  the is operator only considers reference conversions, boxing conversions, and unboxing conversions. Other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, are not considered.

like

```
String[] test = { "1", "2" };
object o = test;

if (o is string[])
{
   Console.WriteLine("this is string array");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(value.GetType() == typeof(string[]))
{
  ..
}
```